# Bacula: how to run a script after 2 jobs are finished?

Tags: backup, configuration, bacula

There is a `Run After` parameter in Bacula configs. But what if I need to wait for several jobs to finish and then run my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make all the jobs but one have the same [priority](http://wiki.bacula.org/doku.php?id=bacula_manual:the_job_resource#priority_number), the same start time, and set [concurrency](http://wiki.bacula.org/doku.php?id=bacula_manual:the_job_resource#maximum_concurrent_jobs_number) to 1, and [disallow mixed priorities](http://wiki.bacula.org/doku.php?id=bacula_manual:the_job_resource#allow_mixed_priority_yesno). Then for the last job, set a lower priority, and schedule it so it starts a minute (or few) later than your other jobs. Put the `Run After` only on that last job.

For example, let's say you have job1, job2, job3, job4 and job5. job1-4 would have `priority=10`, and job5 would have `priority=20` and `Run After`. What would happen is bacula will queue job1-4 to at the same time, but run them one by one (due to `Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 1`). Only when all of them complete, would a job5 be run (due to `Allow Mixed Priority=no` it will wait for all higher priority jobs to complete before it starts), and only when job5 completes, will bacula run `Run After Job` script). So, the script will be run only after all of job1-5 complete.

You can even keep concurrency higher than 1, if you want to run several jobs in parallel - it would still work.

Comment: looks like it should work)

Answer (score 1):

Put all of your related jobs into a single script and then use Run After.

Comment: What do you mean? How can I put bacula jobs configs into a script?